# Overlapping/Overlaying one view with a splash image

Tags: android, android-layout, opencv

I am building an Android Application. I am using OpenCV3's `NativeCameraView` LayoutElement and I want to put a splash image above it.

The original layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/baseRelativeLayout">

    <org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:id="@+id/color_blob_detection_activity_surface_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it shows me the camera feed using the NativeCameraView of Open CV. I can then do image processing on what ever way I like.

However, I want to add a splash image overlay right above it. What I did was to add an imageView, as such:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSplashScreen"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/screen_1"
    android:contentDescription="splashScreen"/>
```

However, even if the "Design" tab showed that my splash screen imageView was above the OpenCV's cameraView, my application does not show the splash image at all.

I then tried placing the openCV Camera Object and the ImageView on separate Relative Views as such:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/baseRelativeLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewSplashScreen"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/screen_1"
            android:contentDescription="splashScreen"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:id="@+id/color_blob_detection_activity_surface_view" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, that did not work as well, even if I swapped their position.

Lastly, I also used the FrameLayout as such:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/baseRelativeLayout">

    <org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/color_blob_detection_activity_surface_view"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBitmapResult"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:contentDescription="resultScreen"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

But to no avail.

How can I resolve this layout problem? I feel like I'm overlooking something simple here.

Answer (score 0):

Just use layout_above or layout_below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id\relativeLayout1">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSplashScreen"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/screen_1"
    android:contentDescription="splashScreen"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!--<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id\relativeLayout1">
    <org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:id="@+id/color_blob_detection_activity_surface_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing this wrong, but `layout_below` puts the view below, not under, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout is for views stacking linearly one by one.

FrameLayout is used for views stacked on top of each other.

Relative Layout is for more complex views. With relative attributes between the views.

Comment: Mind expounding on that and giving an example using my code?

Comment: take a look at the links and start from the basics.

Comment: Neither your links show how to use a FrameLayout to stack views above one another.

Comment: Add the camera view first then the other one. If its not working paste the code.

Comment: the visibility is GONE therefore u dont see the view. set it to visibile and then change it at your later on.

Comment: My bad, actually that's the wrong code, I set the visibility to visible and set the src to point to a drawable resource and I still get nothing.